# How to create a Json from an Array with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, json

I have 5 categories, each category has 3 items.

I have the array:

```
var myArray = ["Item1", "Item2", "Item3"];
```

What is the easiest way to create a Json from it without hardcoding it ?

The array in production can have thousands of items.

Comment: `JSON.stringify( javascriptVariable)`

Comment: And that variable I create it normally with fors and ifs ?

Comment: Doesn't matter, whichever variable you want to jsonize, you can via the above command. Maybe you should post your code to show exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pure javascript:

```
JSON.stringify(myArray);
```

You can use [json.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) for compatibility with <=IE7